# Kommasetzung bei eingebetteten Beispielabschnitten

Tags: comma, typography

Um Fachtexte in einem lockeren Stil zu halten und den Lesefluss zu fördern, sehen Autoren immer häufiger davon ab, formale Abbildungen zu verwenden (vom Text abgesetzt und mit eigenen Bildunterschriften), auf die man sich mit Wendungen wie *siehe Abb. 1* beziehen müsste. Stattdessen werden die illustrierenden Beispiele direkt in den Text eingebettet.

Wie man in folgenden Beispielen sieht, sieht das Komma an jeder Stelle verloren aus.

Stellt man es dem Beispiel voran,

> Block mit Beispiel, Grafik, Formel o.ä.

trennt es zu sehr vom Beispiel.

Lässt man es dem Beispiel folgen

> Block mit Beispiel, Grafik, Formel o.ä.

, sieht es wirklich sehr komisch aus (auch wegen des Leerzeichens direkt dahinter).

Mir geht es um die Fälle, in denen grammatikalisch ein Komma stehen muss. Wenn der Text durch eine illustrative Einfügung genau dort unterbrochen wird, wo das Komma stehen müsste. Dieser Fall ist keine Seltenheit, wenn man eine Argumentation mit Beispielen unterfüttert.

Wie sind die Komma- bzw. typographischen Regeln hierzu?

Comment: Beispiele dieser Art sollten idealerweise nicht im Fließtext stehen, sondern in ihren eigenen »Boxen« (in TeX-Terminologie). Für Beispiele, die im Fließtext stehen können, wie Zitate, sollten die gültigen Regeln für Anführungszeichen hergenommen werden.

Comment: Aber um der Beantwortung der Frage näherzukommen: Ich würde das Komma in beiden Beispielen ganz weglassen. Vor dem Beispiel gegebenenfalls ein Doppelpunkt, dahinter nichts.

Comment: So mache ich es häufig: Vor dem Beispielblock setze ich einen Doppelpunkt. Aber zum einen ist das langweilig (stereotyp bis stupide, vor allem wenn ein Text davor strotzt), zum anderen habe ich in englischsprachigen Literatur häufig ein Komma vor der Box gesehen. Wie bereits gesagt, ich meine eher nicht Texteinwürfe, sondern fernliegendere Text- oder Medientypen.

Comment: Ich würde umformulieren, so dass Du keinen Nebensatz brauchst, der nach einem Einschub weitergeht. Wenn Du so viel einzuschieben hast, dass es nicht in den Fließtext passt, weiss der Leser am Ende des Einschubs sowieso nicht mehr, wie der Satz vor dem Einschub angefangen hat.

Comment: @Robert, genau so sieht die typische Alternative aktuell für mich aus. Nun gibt es aber auch Wenn-dann-Sätze, wo an jedem Part ein Beispiel hängt. In einem mündlichen Vortrag könnte man sowas ohne weiteres mit wechselnden "Dias" kombinieren...

Comment: Bzgl. deinem Beispiel: Das zweite ist einfach falsch. (Das ändert natürlich nichts an deiner Frage, aber ich finde, das sollte gesagt werden.)

Comment: Gerade bei mathematischen Formeln sieht man nicht selten den Fall, dass das oder die Satzzeichen Teil des Formelblocks sind, also eine dritte Möglichkeit. Ich finde aber auch, dass die beste Lösung eine Formulierung ist, die das Problem einfach umgeht.

Answer (score 6):

Der Text sollte nicht an genau dieser Stelle durch ein Beispiel unterbrochen werden. Welche syntaktische Rolle spielt es denn im Satz, die genau diese Position rechtfertigt? Gerechtfertigt wäre die Unterbrechung mitten im Satz, wenn es sich z.B. eine Apposition handelt:

Die Äußerung

> Ich mach dich platt!

ist bedrohlich.

Wenn das Beispiel aber nur eine Äußerung ist, von der der Fließtext *insgesamt* handelt, dann gibt es keinen Grund, sie genau zwischen Nebensatz und Hauptsatz zu zwängen:

Diese Äußerung ist bedrohlich:

> Ich mach dich platt!

Comment: Stimmt schon. Aber meine Beispieltexte sind nur Platzhalter. Gerade bei StackOverflow hat man es oft mit Code-Abschnitten zu tun. Auch in Lehrbüchern gibt es solche Einschübe  - je nach Sachgebiet - in Form von Screenshots, Codeabschnitte, Grafiken, Formeln, usw. Vielleicht hätte ich besser nicht Text genommen.

Comment: Ich habe die Problemstellung noch einmal etwas klarer formuliert. Es geht um einen lockeren Schreibstil.

Comment: Also so etwas wie: 
Es wurden auch Drohungen, z.B. "Stirb!", ausgesprochen
?

Comment: Nein, es geht um Fachtexte, die sich eher nicht mit "Literatur" auseinandersetzen. Handbücher, Lehrbücher usw. Ich muss wohl meine Frage doch noch einmal überarbeiten.

Comment: Ich habe die Frage nochmals bearbeitet. Deine Antwort behält m.E. ihre Gültigkeit für Fälle in denen es ums Schreiben geht.

Answer (score 4):

Die Grammatik hält einen Satz von Regeln bereit, mit denen festgelegt werden, wie mehrere **Wörter** zu einem Satz verbunden werden können. Wichtig ist, dass es dabei um *Wörter* geht, zu denen in diesem Zusammenhang auch *Zahlen* gehören können, aber selbst da betritt man schon Grenzregionen des Geltungsgebietes der Grammatik.

Wenn man in einem Satz Dinge einbaut, die auch im weitesten Sinn keine Wörter mehr sind, sondern Emoticons, Bilder, ganze Absätze oder — im Internet durchaus möglich — sogar Videos, dann hat man das Reich, in dem die Grammatik noch das Sagen hat, bereits hinter sich gelassen.

Es gibt zwei Möglichkeiten: Wenn man grammatisch korrekte Sätze schreiben will, fügt man in die Sätze nur Wörter (und ab und zu ein paar Zahlen) ein, und verweist auf andere Elemente in altgewohnter Weise.

Die andere Möglichkeit lautet: Man bastelt sich einen Satz eigener Erweiterungsregeln der deutschen Grammatik, der eine Obermenge der etablierten Regeln ist, und hält sich dann möglichst konsequent an diesen erweiterten Regelsatz.

Comment: Stimmt, jetzt sehe auch ich das Schild "SIE VERLASSEN DEN  GRAMMATIKALISCHEN SEKTOR" - danke für den Augenöffner :-) Mit der Konsequenz hatte ich das bislang gar nicht betrachtet.

Answer (score 3):

Formal geregelt ist diese Situation meines Wissens nicht.
Rein vom persönlichen Sprachgefühl her würde ich das Komma in dieser Situation schlicht weglassen. Seine Gliederungsfunktion wird von dem Einschub ausreichend mit erfüllt.

Wessen Sprachgefühl das nicht erträgt, der sollte diese Art Einschübe am besten ganz vermeiden.